# GWT:can i put Delay for few seconds after showing a popup

Tags: gwt

I have small GWT application , in which i am showing a popup on success

```
           if(success){
               DescoratedPopupPanel popup = new DecoratedPopupPanel();
               popup.show();
               //Now here i want to wait for like 5 secs and then 
               popup.hide();
             }
```

Any idea how can i put a dealay of 5 secs before hiding the popup

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the code that uses Timer to produce 5 secs delay:

```
        final DecoratedPopupPanel popup = new DecoratedPopupPanel();
        popup.show();
        // Now here i want to wait for like 5 secs and then
        Timer timer = new Timer()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                popup.hide();
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(5000);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html) which lets you schedule a task in the future.

As Thomas Broyer mentioned in the comments, you could also use [com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler#scheduleFixedDelay()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleFixedDelay%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand,%20int%29) with a `RepeatingCommand` that always returns false to indicate that it should only be executed once.

Comment: Or use `com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler`; the main difference is that a `Timer` can be cancelled, not a `ScheduledCommand`.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer How would you use Scheduler with a fixed delay for a non-repeating task, though? The javadoc of the two methods that include a delay are for repeating task if I see it correctly.

Comment: Ah, right! You can use a `RepeatingCommand` that unconditionally returns `false` though, as an equivalent to a `ScheduledCommand`.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not notice the boolean return value. Cheers, this is good to know. Will update the question accordingly.